# jQuery Image slide up and down using nav

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slide, nav

I have 3 screenshots which are postioned negatively using absolute postioning. Now further below in the page I have a nav containing 3 anchor tags which correspond to each of the 3 screenshots in the aforementioned gallery.

I want the pertinent image to slide up (after of course the currently active screenshot slides down) using the nav anchor link as controls when I **hover** over them.

I have the below syntax.

**THE HTML**

```
<ul id="gallery">
<li><img src="./index_files/window1_841x461px.png"></li>
<li><img src="./index_files/window2_841x461px.png"></li>
<li><img src="./index_files/window3_841x461px.png"></li>
</ul>
```

**THE JS**

```
$("ul#gallery li:first").css({bottom: '0'}).addClass("on");
$("#featureList a:first").addClass("on");   

$("#featureList a").hover(function() {

    if ($(this).hasClass("on")) {

    }
    else {

        $("#featureList a.on").removeClass("on");

        var item = $(this);
        var item_index = $(this).index();

        item.addClass("on");

        $("ul#gallery li.on").stop().animate({bottom: '-400px'}, function() {
            $(this).removeClass("on");
            $("ul#gallery li").eq(item_index).stop().animate({bottom: '0'}).addClass("on");
        });

    }

});
```

This seems to be working fine - with one minor glitch - if I hover vigourosly and continusily over the nav controls the whole thing looses its synch and basically nothin comes up. HELP!!!!!!

Comment: Could you please provide a jsfiddle example.

Comment: The example I have is quite tricky to put inside a jsfiddle. I have a url however I cannot share it since it is corporate stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I've had success using jQuery .stop() to prevent over-queueing of animations.  It might help you.

http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Comment: Problem is I am already using .stop() - if you look carefully at the code you could see I am using it. However the problem persists